# iOS: How to check if In-App purchase enabled?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, user-permissions

There are some function to check if user enable some feature. Just like location or camera roll.

But, how to check if In-App purchase enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this may help on you:

#### Swift

```
if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

    // you can, so start adding the payment to the payment queue
} else {

    // you may not, handle the rejection
}
```

#### ObjC

```
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {

     // you can, so start adding the payment to the payment queue
} else {

     // you may not, handle the rejection
}
```

---

it is from the [`SKPaymentQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue) class reference about `canMakePayments()` class method:

> `true` if the user is allowed to authorize payment. `false` if they do not have permission.

and further explanation for the same method:

> An iPhone can be restricted from accessing the Apple App Store. For example, parents can restrict their children’s ability to purchase additional content. Your application should confirm that the user is allowed to authorize payments before adding a payment to the queue. Your application may also want to alter its behavior or appearance when the user is not allowed to authorize payments.